# Disable bold fonts on Google search results

Tags: google-search, user-stylesheets

Today Google started to display search results in a bold font. How can I bring back the normal way in which search results were displayed?

[image: a screenshot showing the bold]

Comment: This is something Google is experimenting with, refer http://www.texient.com/2014/03/google-search-result-layout-big-font-changes.html

Comment: Thanks @SunilManheri.Today my search results came back to the normal way it used to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The titles of the search results aren't bold; instead, the font size is now 18px rather than 16px like it was previously.

Also, this change doesn't affect only Google Chrome. I use Firefox and I see the change too.

Lastly, the change seems to come and go. I see it one day but not the next. As Sunil Manheri commented above, Google seems to be experimenting with changes to their search engine results pages (SERPs).

I hate the new font size and much prefer 16px. I added the following CSS rule to my user stylesheet (userContent.css in my Firefox profile) to force Google's SERP titles to be 16px:

```css
body#gsr h3.r {
  font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Google recently removed support for user stylesheets from Chrome (in an effort to dumb down their browser even more than it already is). Fortunately for Chrome users (definitely not me), user styles can be added to Chrome using the [Stylish extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe).

Answer (score 1):

For those who are looking for a cross-browser solution, I have written a small bookmarklet, which will reduce the font size as well as to add underline to hyperlinks:

[image]

See the blog I posted on the topic for further information: http://techawakening.org/?p=2800

Answer (score 0):

Google switched to a larger size in their font. (I agree Arial, or whatever it is, is ugly at that size) I solved the problem by setting that page to 90% zoom.  (Chrome browser.) Thankfully, the zoom feature applies only to specific pages, and remembers.

Answer (score 0):

how to bold text in description google search?

Bolding, underlining, bullets all help to structure information in an educational manner (see all the texts books you read in college). Google likes it when it thinks you are providing educational relevant material. If a word is in your link, in your title a bolded header and underlined in the body google know this is an important topic on your page as well as the reade

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

I using meta description : I bold ❺⓿% and ❶⓿⓿ 
View:
https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&q=mua+ban+nah+dat&oq=mua+ban+nah+dat&gs_l=serp.3..0i10j0i22i30l9.3348.4965.0.5190.15.15.0.0.0.0.152.1324.12j3.15.0....0...1c.1.38.serp..1.14.1185.QAQjB4ETEi0