# How can I fix the Google Search tabs in a custom order?

Tags: google-search, userscripts, user-stylesheets

This is the well-known top bar of the *google.com* Google Search results page:

[image: the Google Search top bar]

I regularly click on a wrong tab because I am used to certain positions of the tabs, and would like to have the Shopping tab either be invisible, or under the 'More' dropdown menu, and have the 'Images' tab permanently in the second place, to the right of 'All'.

**Is there a way (esp. in Firefox) to have the Google Search tabs that appear on top of the search results page remain in a specified position?**

Google itself does not provide a way to customize *google.com* further than the options on [this page](https://support.google.com/toolbar/answer/9271) (limited to language, safe search, and a few privacy settings), only to [create semi-customizable search engines](https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/all) that can be implemented on existing sites. I mention this because one of the seemingly promising hits when searching for a solution was [this page](https://support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/4513783), which turned out to be only for the aforementioned customizable engine.

Neither was I able to find a Firefox plugin for it, nor a Tampermonkey script. I can see the divs of the tabs have a class name of `hdtb-mitem`, and their child spans the class names `bmaJhd` and `iJddsb`, but I wouldn't know how to target the 'Shopping' tab specifically (unless there is a way to filter out any link containing a keyword, like 'shopping'), and using uBlock I can't seem to block only that tab, specifically.

Comment: I'm not sure if the [userscripts] tag is appropriate here. Please let me know or remove it if it has no place here.

Comment: [tag:userscripts] migth be fine but you should show what you have tried as nowadays asking to find / recommend stuff is off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 1):

If you dislikes the Google way of changing the Google search user interface then rather than playing with customizing it consider to use another tool as Google continually do "small" changes to the user interface" and fixing certain user interface might require to invest a lot of time learning scripting and handling tools and will require frequent maintenance.

As web app developers use tools that automatically generates the code that is delivered to the end-user some customizations are becoming very hard and even imposible to keep working over the time. Apps like Google Search that apparently have being the same over the years are changed continually.

---

I have not analysed how is nowadays Google Search working but I assume that it 's not too different than other modern well designed web apps: it uses HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

You might search for code snippets and web browser extensions using keywords like:

- user script
- user style
- user stylesheet

The web browser extensions might not strictly necessary as the scripts  might be handled directly using your favorite web developer tools.

Resources

- [Understanding CSS for user styling in a browser](https://superuser.com/q/234952/152004)
- [Custom per-site stylesheet extension for Firefox](https://superuser.com/q/128666/152004)

Related

- [Disable bold fonts on Google search results](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/58643/88163)